# How do I run through the contents of a MS SQL table and put the rows into a alter table?

Tags: sql-server, database, while-loop, alter-table

I'm looking to run through the contents of a table (MS SQL), collect the names in a column and put them in an alter table loop.

For example:

```
Bank names(column name) | Desc (column name)

Nationwide   | Example

HSBC         | Example

Halifax      | Example
```

---

```
ALTER TABLE banks

ADD (rows from bank table) varchar(255);
```

---

End result:

altered another table:

```
(Columns within new table \/)

Nationwide | HSBC | Halifax
```

Comment: Look into doing a `Pivot` with the values contained in the column Bank names,  (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample/)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here ? This doesn't sounds like a good way of doing things

Comment: what I forgot to say is the new table is an existing table (which is why I'm altering the table). I'm trying the dynamically add a new column when a row is added in another table

Comment: This is not how relational databases work. You don't add new columns to accommodate row values. Something here has gone very very wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can form dynamic sql statements to do this.

```
--Table to hold the banks while you work
CREATE TABLE #firsttable (Bank VARCHAR(20), Descr VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #firsttable
(
    Bank
  , Descr
)
VALUES
('Nationwide', 'blah')
, ('HSBC','blah blah')
, ('Halifax', 'blah blah blah')

--The existing table you will be modifying
CREATE TABLE #existingtable (id INT)

--Variables
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @currentbank VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @banksleft INT

SELECT @banksleft = COUNT(1) FROM #firsttable;

--Loop through the banks
WHILE (@banksleft > 0)
    BEGIN
    SELECT @currentbank = bank FROM #firsttable;
    SELECT @sql = 'ALTER TABLE #existingtable ADD ' +  '[' + @currentbank  + '] varchar(255);' FROM #firsttable 

    --Run the alter statement
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    --Get rid of the bank you have just added as a column
    DELETE
    FROM #firsttable WHERE Bank = @currentbank;
    --Reset the counter
    SELECT @banksleft = COUNT(1) FROM #firsttable;

    end

--To show the columns added to the table
SELECT * FROM #existingtable AS e;

--Cleanup
DROP TABLE #firsttable;
DROP TABLE #existingtable;
```